# Function to create buttons in a form

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface, button

I know the usual way to define a button in PowerShell, but I would like to create a function to do this to lighten up the script a little bit, since I have a lot of buttons.

I want to create a function to simply create a button with the following parameters:

- name
- pos-X
- pos-Y
- size-X
- size-Y
- button text
- function to call on click

This is how I define the function at the beginning of the script

```
function c_button ($bname, $posx, $posy, $sizex, $sizey, $btext, $Bfunction)
  {
    $bname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
    $bname.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($posx,$posy) 
    $bname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sizex, $sizey) 
    $bname.Text = $btext
    $bname.Add_Click({$Bfunction}) 
  }
```

And this is how I called the function:

```
c_button "Button1" 10 10 150 25 "Open Serverlist file" "list"
$form.Controls.Add($Button1)
```

This should replace a standard call like this:

```
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
$button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150, 25) 
$button1.Text = "Open Serverlist file"
$button1.Add_Click({list}) 
$form.Controls.Add($Button1)
```

I tried several ways to call the function, with `()`, inside the `$form.Add`, but they all failed. Nothing is displayed.

I also tried it for `Forms.Label` and `Forms.CheckBox` with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to echo `$bname` inside the function, otherwise it won't return anything for the caller to work with:

```
function c_button ($posx, $posy, $sizex, $sizey, $btext, $Bfunction) {
  $bname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $bname.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($posx,$posy)
  $bname.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($sizex, $sizey)
  $bname.Text = $btext
  $bname.Add_Click($Bfunction)

  $bname
}
```

Then capture the function output in a variable and add that to the form:

```
$getList = {
  # code for listing the file here
}

$Button1 = c_button 10 10 150 25 "Open Serverlist file" $getList
$form.Controls.Add($Button1)
```

or call the function directly in a subexpression in the `Add()` method (note the double parentheses):

```
$form.Controls.Add((c_button 10 10 150 25 "Open Serverlist file" $getList))
```

Comment: The form.add version tried it before.Tried it agaian, no result. Good idea with the putting the output in a variable, but I still don't get any button.

Comment: @Zsolt Because your function doesn't return anything. See updated answer.

Comment: Onw more question: is it possible to call a function from a variable? In the button example i call the function "list" and add it to the button.click({$bfunction}) but the burton doesn't work. If i call it outside the function for every button like before it is ok. I tryedalso :  button.click({invoke-function $bfunction }). Thank you!

Comment: @Zsolt Define the functionality as a scriptblock and pass that to the parameter `$Bfunction`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works well! I saved so far over 160 lines of code!

Comment: @Zsolt As a side-note: I'd recommend using a more canonical name for the function (e.g. `New-Button`).